# SQLite Generic Repository : Cannot compile: TypeAs

Tags: c#, sqlite

Hello im trying to achieve a generic SQlite repository.

This will allow me to make my coding easier but im encountering some difficulties or maybe doing something wrong.

To illustrate my purpose, ive got my Models classes. Below the inheritance tree.

ModelBase (abstract)

-- ModelBaseID (public **int** ID property primary key)

-- ModelBaseGUID (public **Guid** GUID property primary key)

All my models classes will inherit either from ModelBaseID, either from ModelBaseGUID depending on the primary key type i need.

Below my Generic Repository

```
        public class SQLiteRepository<T> where T : class, new()
        {
    ...

     public async Task<T> GetItemAsync(object id, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
            {
T x = null;

   if (id is int)
            {
                int intID = (int)id;
                try
                {
                    x = await database.Table<T>().Where(item => (item as ModelBaseID).ID == intID).FirstOrDefaultAsync();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {

                    throw;
                }

        }
        else if (id is Guid)
        {
            Guid GuidID = (Guid)id;
            try
            {
                x = await database.Table<T>().Where(item => (item as ModelBaseGUID).GUID == GuidID).FirstOrDefaultAsync();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                throw;
            }

        }
```

I ve got error -> Cannot compile: TypeAs due to my Where casting expression. Any ideas on an elegant solution to this issue ?

Comment: Whats the exact error you are getting? Also, if you are doing typechecking and casting, then your code is not really generic. I suggest you read more on generics.

Comment: I have built a similar concept for a SQLite generic repository that must do some similar casting checks. It works flawlessly and makes life a lot easier. Can you please share at least the rest of the GetItemAsync method, so I can best answer your question.